# How do I get the number of visible characters from a UTF-8 encoded char*?

Tags: c++, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 encoded `char*`.

Is there a standard function to calculate the number of visible characters represented by the byte array?

I'm on Red Hat (RHEL 5).

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  glib here I come!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the iconv library: man iconv_open. One can convert the utf-8 string into say UCS-2 or UCS-4 where characters are of the same size. iconv is also (relatively) portable and not Linux or GNU specific.

If Glib, suggested before, is available to you (beware: it is GPLed) then use it as it is a better way.

Comment: Oh. Mea culpa. Then forget the iconv stuff.

Comment: This isn't a correct answer to "get the number of visible characters", because codepoints are not the same thing as visible characters. A Unicode grapheme can composed out of any number of code points.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `glib.h`, has [g_utf8_strlen()](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-strlen)

Check out [this page for more information (including three implementations of an algo to do this)](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-05-faster-utf8-strlen.html)

Comment: The documentation you pointed to doesn't indicate whether it counts non-independent characters like combining characters or diacritics.  Do you know whether it does?

Comment: I think the utf8 parlance for what you speak of is graphemes, without the use of that term I would not take it to mean combining characters or diacritics.

Comment: g_utf8_strlen() only counts code points within a UTF-8 string. Thus, if you had "e\u0341" (U+0341 is a combining acute accent), you'd get 2, while the string itself will display as é.

Comment: That whole second link seems to be a lesson in premature optimization.

Comment: I disagree with this latter remark. Library code is wholly different from application code: it ought to be as fast as possible or it'll be shunned from critical performance code. Furthermore, I would argue it's not premature in the sense that it's been thought and measured and is not the result of a misconception.